# Orocommerce import an important number of product attributes

Tags: mysql, orocommerce

I am using Orocommerce Community Edition 4.2.2 and I have an issue when creating several product attributes.

When creating a product attribute, it seems to create behind the scene a secondary index. The pre-defined max number of secondary indexes in a table is set to 64 in MySQL. I currently hit this limit.

I get the same error as mentioned in this [post](https://forum.oroinc.com/orocommerce/topic/import-more-than-64-attributes-to-product-table.-mysql.-to-many-keys-specified/):

Is there any workaround (except increasing mysql MAX_INDEXES)? The post above mentions this is referred to OroCommerce internal tracker BB-9994. Any updates on this ticket ?

Answer (score 0):

You can review all the attributes and make as match as you can not filterable and not sortable to reduce the number of indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. All our attributes are already not filterable and sortable. Though, we are reaching this limit. Any other workaround that you may suggest.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: These changes should be done in advance. The goal is to make attributes serialized fields instead of table columns. If you have too many enum/multienum fields - we can recommend converting as much as you can of them to strings.